# Examples of magazine/newspaper publication websites using Craft?

Tags: templating

I was just wondering if anyone has any examples of any mag/newspaper websites that use Craft? I'm interested to see the blend of technology or how the layouts turned out. Thanks!

Comment: Subjective, list-based, no problem to be solved?

Comment: As Fred mentioned, this question doesn't really fit the Stack Exchange format of trying to solve a technical question. It's more of a request for examples of other folks' finished projects. A better place to ask a question like this would be on the [Craft Google+ community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/106505340287442511226). That all being said, we'll close this question as being "off-topic".

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Straighupcraft gallery](http://straightupcraft.com/project-gallery). Maybe you'll find something there.